# How can I replace a sub-string of a specific column by something I want in Pandas of Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

[image]

I want to replace all the 'k' by 000 in the column Vehicle Value, which means the data in Vehicle Value should be represented as 25000,100000,10000.....

How can I do it? Does 'Pandas' have a function to achieve it?

Comment: Does the column always end in `k`? And do you want it as a numeric or another string? As something like: `pd.to_numeric(df['Vehicle Value'].str[:-1]) * 1000` might be what you're after.

Comment: Or if that's not the case... maybe: `df['Vehicle Value'].str.replace('k$', '000')` (maybe use `pd.to_numeric` on that?)

Comment: Thanks! What does '$' follow by k mean?

Comment: It's a regular expression... `$` means end of string... so it basically means replace the last `k` in the string if it exists with `000`

Comment: Note... it won't do what's expected though if your Value is say for instance "2.5k"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might work for you is separating out the potential "value" and any potential "multiplier suffix", so let's say that your `df['Vehicle Value']` was:

```
s = pd.Series(['25k', '1.25m', '100k', '500', '2.5k'])
```

Our expected result there should be `[25000, 1250000, 100000, 500, 2500]`. So we do:

```
vm = s.str.extract('(?P<value>.*?)(?P<multiplier>[km])?$')
```

Which gives:

```
      value multiplier
0    25          k
1  1.25          m
2   100          k
3   500        NaN
4   2.5          k
```

Then convert the multiplier to a number (k=1,000, m=1,000,000 and if there isn't one specified - just keep it as 1), then multiply the value with it, eg:

```
df['Numeric Vehicle Value'] = pd.to_numeric(vm['value']) * vm['multiplier'].replace({'k': 1000, 'm': 1000000}).fillna(1)
```